# Unity - loading configuration, resolving types in different namespace

Tags: c#, wcf, unity-container

Situation: 2 projects
1 project is of type WCF Service Library (ProjA)
1 project is a console application with Unity references (ProjB)

Inside ProjB I want to do UnityContainer.LoadConfiguration and resolve types which are in ProjA.

I have tried this in ProjB.AppConfig file

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <alias alias="IClass" type="OtherNameSpace.IClass, OtherNameSpace"/>
    <alias alias="Class" type="OtherNameSpace.Class, OtherNameSpace"/>
    <container>
        <register type="IClass" mapTo="Class"/>
    </container>
</unity>
```

For reference the ProjB namespace is ClientHost and ProjB namespace is OtherNameSpace.

The exception I get is: The type name or alias OtherNameSoace.IClass, OtherNameSpace could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.

Comment: `type="OtherNameSpace.IClass, OtherNameSpace"` I believe the second parameter needs to be the name of the project's output DLL, not the namespace. Try changing to `type="OtherNameSpace.IClass, (ProjBDllName)"` where "(ProjBDllName)" is the name of the ProjB dll without the extension.

Comment: The project name is the same as the namespace. E.g. it is type="OtherNameSpace.IClass, OtherNameSpace" - OtherNameSpace is the namespace and the project b name.